# Water coming from the slab under the tub?

Tags: plumbing, leak, bathtub, slab

My house was built in 62, with cast iron pipes. They failed and I had them re-lined (CIPP). My guest bathroom backs up to my master bedroom closet.

The other day when the kids were in the bath, I noticed water on my closet floor. I assumed it was the drain, so I cut a hole and installed an access panel so that I could swap out the drain. Done, no leaks, until everyone took a bath, then water again.

I left a camera there as it would only happen when I wasn’t watching it. Then boom, water was coming up from around the PVC waste pipe. No clue what to do now.

Comment: Some photos would help

Comment: suspecting the kids to be the culprit

Answer (score 1):

It could be simple explanation. It never happens when you are watching.
It only happens when the family (and the kids) take a bath.

Check what your kids are doing in the bath (splashing/overflow).